# Asterisk setup steps in public network

Tags: asterisk, voip, linphone

I am working on a VoIP project.

We want to use Linphone, a SIP client software, to do video-call between
different NATs. We want to use Asterisk as the SIP server and ICE server.

Question: how to configure Asterisk server, so that we can use it as the SIP
server? Hope someone can give some detailed configuration steps.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Question on stackoverflow must show some effort in dooing what you asking. You can read any book about asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

This can get you started:
http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/asterisk_voip_ipphone.html

But, yes, please read a book (as the above comment states), or manual, or search the web... there are plenty of tutorials and info!